# Where can players find other players to team up against organized squads?

Tags: ps3, battlefield-bad-company-2

I have been gaming with BC2 for a few months now and enjoying it.  In some rush/conquest games its obvious that the other team is very well organised, to the point of "stacking" one team over the other.

To even the odds, is there a forum for getting players together at certain times to team up against these organised squads?

Comment: I tried to edit this as best as I could, but I'm still really confused as to what you were asking. Could you please clarify the intention of this question?

Comment: See http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ringer&defid=1340477 - back in the day, the best place to be a ringer was #ringer.  Not sure if that's true anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Get your own organized team or join a server that scrambles the teams.

Comment: yeah - sorry mana - I was wondering if there is a website that allows one to arrange teams or squads before hand to be more organised rather that going one out against those who organise themselves this is quite obvious especially against European teams.